# Use Objects.requireNonNull() to validate the request body like Objects.requireNonNull(body.getName()) return error code

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

when I use the Objects.requireNonNull() to validate the request body, some api return error code 400, others return 500. It should be 400, because the body sent to server side is invalid. I am now confused, do anyone know how to address this. Thanks!

```
@PostMapping(value = "/referencing-courses")
public Object get(@RequestBody Criteria criteria) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(criteria, "body is required");
        Objects.requireNonNull(criteria.getContentId(), "contentId is required.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(criteria.getSchemaVersion(), "schemaVersion is required.");
        return findLatestTreeRevisionReference.find(criteria);
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand how requireNonNull works?

Comment: Use `@Valid` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`Objects.requireNonNull()` throws a `NullPointerException if the passed parameter is null. Exceptions trigger an Internal Server Error (500).

The status code 400 is not caused by the exception but because controller parameters are not null by default and spring validates this.

As [@chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic) pointed out in the comments, you can use `@Valid`:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/referencing-courses")
public Object get(@RequestBody @Valid Criteria criteria) {
        return findLatestTreeRevisionReference.find(criteria);
    }
```

For this to work, `Criteria` needs to use proper annotations:

```java
public class Criteria{
    @NotNull
    private String contentId;
    @NotNull
    private String schemaVersion;

    //Getters/Setters

}
```

You can also create a custom exception and/or exception handler in your controller as described [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) if `@Valid` is not viable.

For example, you could catch every NullPointerException in your controller and send back a 400 Bad Request status:

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) 
@ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
public void handleNPE() {
    //Done by @ResponseStatus
}
```

However, NullPointerExceptions might occur because of different reasons than the user sending an invalid request. In order to bypass that issue, you can create your own exception that translates to the error 400:

```java
 @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Request body invalid")
 public class InvalidBodyException extends RuntimeException {
     //No need for additional logic
 }
```

You can then make your own method that does the null check and use that instead of `Objects.requireNonNull`:

```java
public void requireNonNull(Object o){
    if(o==null){
        throw new InvalidBodyException();
    }
}
```